# Error in Maven project build-"Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.index.ArtifactInfo"

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, maven

Hi All when I am trying to build or clean the Maven project I got below error 
can any help me ?

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'POM-SeleniumProject-MVN'.
Could not initialize class org.apache.maven.index.ArtifactInfo[image]

Answer (score 2):

@Mahesh, I have below suggestions:-

**# Solution 1**

- Go to your eclipse installation folder
- Run "eclipse.exe -clean"

**# Solution 2**

- Uninstall Netbeans because Eclipse and Netbeans are both might using the same workspace

**# Solution 3**

- Right click project, remove maven nature (or in newer eclipse, "Maven->Disable Maven Nature")
- mvn eclipse:clean (with project open in eclipse/STS)
- delete the project in eclipse (but do not delete the sources)
- Import existing Maven project

**# Solution 4**

- Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries and removed the blue entries starting with M2_REPO.
- After that, I could use Maven -> Update Project again

**# Solution 5**

- Cross-check whether you have [Setup project correctly](http://www.assertselenium.com/eclipse-2/how-to-setup-a-webdriver-project-in-eclipse/)